# Determinando uma string dentro de um switch em C

Tags: c, string, switch

Tenho dúvida em como definir uma string dentro de um `switch` em C, sem precisar fazer uma tabela de constantes para isso.

[image: Código]

A variável `nome_lanche` é do tipo `char`, mas esta com o número de caracteres definido, então estou usando como uma `string`.

Preciso que a variável esteja vazia antes do `switch` e após a passada pelo switch se o caso for verdadeiro essa recebera o valor designado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seguem 3 maneiras de se resolver o problema sem usar uma tabela de constantes.

**1)** Ponteiro char para string constante:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    char * nome_lanche = NULL;
    int preco_lanche = 0;
    int cod_lanche = atoi( argv[1] );

    switch( cod_lanche )
    {
        case 0:
            nome_lanche = "macarrao";
            preco_lanche = 10;
            break;

        case 100:
            nome_lanche = "hamburger";
            preco_lanche = 5;
            break;

        default:
            nome_lanche = "invalido";
            preco_lanche = -1;
            break;
    }

    printf("Codigo: %d\n", cod_lanche );
    printf("Nome: %s\n", nome_lanche );
    printf("Preco: %d\n", preco_lanche );

    return 0;
}

/* fim-de-arquivo */
```

**2)** Alocação estática de memória (vetor de chars):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NOME_MAX_TAM  (100)

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    char nome_lanche[ NOME_MAX_TAM + 1 ] = {0};
    int preco_lanche = 0;
    int cod_lanche = atoi(argv[1]);

    switch( cod_lanche )
    {
        case 0:
            strcpy( nome_lanche, "macarrao" );
            preco_lanche = 10;
            break;

        case 100:
            strcpy( nome_lanche, "hamburger");
            preco_lanche = 5;
            break;

        default:
            strcpy( nome_lanche, "codigo invalido" );
            preco_lanche = -1;
            break;
    }

    printf("Codigo: %d\n", cod_lanche );
    printf("Nome: %s\n", nome_lanche );
    printf("Preco: %d\n", preco_lanche );

    return 0;
}

/* fim-de-arquivo */
```

**3)** Alocação dinâmica de memória:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    char * nome_lanche = NULL;
    int preco_lanche = 0;
    int cod_lanche = atoi(argv[1]);

    switch( cod_lanche )
    {
        case 0:
            nome_lanche = strdup("macarrao");
            preco_lanche = 10;
            break;

        case 100:
            nome_lanche = strdup("hamburger");
            preco_lanche = 5;
            break;

        default:
            nome_lanche = strdup("codigo invalido");
            preco_lanche = -1;
            break;
    }

    printf("Codigo: %d\n", cod_lanche );
    printf("Nome: %s\n", nome_lanche );
    printf("Preco: %d\n", preco_lanche );

    free( nome_lanche );

    return 0;
}

/* fim-de-arquivo */
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 2):

Não é possível. Ou deve usar outras construções da linguagem (`if strcmp()`) ou criar uma tabela auxiliar para cuidar disso (uma tabela *hash* costuma ser usada).

Se pode usar constantes no lugar das *strings*, é melhor.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Então eu devo criar uma tabela de constantes e usar strcpy dentro do switch?

Comment: Se usar uma tabela de constantes não usará *strings* e pode usar `switch`. Se for usar *strings*, aí terá que usar `if` com `strcmp()`.